# Describe someone who is away a lot

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am looking for ways to describe someone who is frequently absent from home or school (and for long periods of time), especially for work-related reasons.

Comment: How about `unavailable`?

Comment: How will you use this single word or phrase in context? You need to clarify this by providing an example sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I would say truant or absentee.

Merriam-Webster gives us:

> Definition of **truant**
>
> :one who shirks duty; especially :one who stays out of school without
>   permission
>
> Definition of **absentee**
>
> :one that is absent: such as a :a proprietor that lives away from his
>   or her estate or business b :one missing from work or school

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 2):

There is a term '**stopout**' but it is often quite derogatory and sometimes comes with an adjective that makes it even more derogatory.

It has a genuine usage but, in the UK at least, it has tended to be used as slang and is reported in the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=stopout).

The [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stopout) reports its more proper meaning and suggests that it is a blend of 'stop' and 'dropout'.

I would look at the links carefully before using it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say **absentee.**

Antidote Antidoise gives us...

> **Definition of absentee**
>
> Someone who should be present at a location or event, but is not
>
> **Ex.** There were four absentees from the training today.

Comment: I don't quite understand how outgoing fits...

Comment: @FelixGoldberg fixed it.